# Store data from a virtual machine on virtual drive or "real" hard disc?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I am preparing to work with virtual machines only on my next PC (which should arrive this wk). (Planning to use virtualbox under Solaris, mainly to virtualize Win XP + Win7-environments).

One question I haven't sorted out yet is where to store the data - I intend to have a system-drive for each setup and a common data-drive. But should I store data in the hosts file-system, or better use virtual disks for that? I'm a bit worried by the thought about a single inverted bit making the whole virtual disk unuseable. Granted that this can happen on real disk as well, but it seems that would be easier to recover the files not concerned by that inverted bit. But maybe that is all unneccessary worry, surely there must be similar tools for VDI etc.

What's your experience and why did you choose which setup for your vbox-installation? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a shared virtual drive is probably not the best idea, simply because you can't really share it with more than one machine at a time.

You are much better off using the shared folder capability of VirtualBox and keeping the files on the host if at all possible.

Answer (score 3):

i always store data for my VBoxes in shared folders on the host so i can use them on multiple machines.

as it sometimes happens, old virtual machines become incompatible when they roll out a major update, so i just have to setup a new machine and not be worried about the data on the machine.